# Javascript Calculator - issues with commas

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript; as in about 3 days new... I am working on creating a calculator to extract data from three input fields and then calculates out to a rough monthly and yearly total. It then uses this total to dynamically build out a table.

For the most part I have everything working, with one exception. If someone types a comma into the input fields it will only recognize the value before the comma. So for example if they type 10,000; it will read it as 10. I've tried to place in a Regex based replace, but it doesn't seem to be working. I may be placing it in the wrong place, but I tried it a few different ways, so now sure.

Below is the portion of the code that I am having trouble with.

```
    <input onblur="findTotal();" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1"/>
    <input onblur="findTotal();" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/>
    <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/>

    <input disabled type="text" name="totalyr" id="totalyr"/>
    <input disabled type="text" name="totalmo" id="totalmo"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function findTotal(){
        var getqty = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<getqty.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(getqty[i].value))
                (tot += parseInt(getqty[i].value));
        }
        document.getElementById('totalmo').value = tot*4;
        document.getElementById('totalyr').value = tot*52;
    }
    </script>
```

I've tried making the inputs numbers as well, but that did nothing.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to allow commas at all in the input?

Comment: Try `parseInt(getqty[i].value.replace(/,/g,''),10)`

Comment: What regex replace did you try?

Comment: Better use parseFloat(getqty[i].value.replace(/,/g,'')) as parseInt will ignore everything after a dot like 123.456 will be capped to 123.

Comment: I'd be fine with disallowing commas all together.

Comment: As for which regex I used, I used .replace(/\D/g,"") 

Going to try out parsefloat now.

Comment: parseFloat is where it's at! Thank you so much everyone. I did some testing with a few different variants and decided to go with the following: 

function findTotal(){
    var getqty = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<getqty.length;i++){
        if(parseFloat(getqty[i].value.replace(/\D/g,'')))
            (tot += parseFloat(getqty[i].value.replace(/\D/g,'')));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Had this yesterday, this is what worked for me

```
    var getqty = document.getElementsByName('qty').value.replace(/,/g, "");
```

alternatively something like

```
    var getqty = +document.getElementByName("qty").value.replace(/[^\de.-]/gi, "");
```